# How do we say 56789 year and other dates?

Tags: dates

I read we could say years differently:

> 1475 - fourteen hundred and seventy five
>
> 1475 - fourteen seventy five

Will it be a mistake if I say:

> 1475 - fourteen hundred seventy five

Then it was hard with 2019, for instance:

> 2019 - two thousand nineteen
>
> 2019 - two thousand and nineteen
>
> 2019 - twenty nineteen
>
> 2019 - twenty and nineteen

But what to do if we have 56789 year.(5 numbers)

> 56789 - fifty six thousand seven hundred eighty nine
>
> 56789 - fifty six thousand AND seven hundred eighty nine
>
> 56789 - fifty six thousand seven hundred AND eighty nine
>
> 56789 - fifty six thousand AND seven hundred AND eighty nine
>
> 56789 - 567 hundred AND eighty nine
>
> 56789 - 567 hundred eighty nine

Or how will it be...?

Comment: Fantasy writers have tackled this idea:  https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Dating_System Maybe asking on [scifi.se] would lead to more productive answers.

Comment: If you wanted to affect a more poetic or archaic style you could use *nineteen and two thousand* for two thousand nineteen. *Twenty and nineteen*, however, is thirty-nine.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe on some car commercials that speak 5 digit prices, I've heard the format XX Y ZZ, e.g. "Fifty-six seven eighty-nine."

Comment: 56,789 is a year far in the future, but it is a year.  It’s a year we may well have reason to reference today.  The OP gives us reason to reference it, right here and now, and in contemporary language.  Neither the eventuality nor the language is remote.

Comment: I think it's unfair to close this question for being about *hypothetical* English, but it is fair to close it as primarily based on personal opinion.  There is no "standard" format for dates in the far future, so everyone will have an individual preference.

Comment: @ LawrenceC okay, then what format would be for a 6-digit number if it's "XX Y ZZ" for the 5-digit one?

Answer (score 1):

Most common is

> twenty nineteen

Less common is

> two thousand nineteen

Least common is

> two thousand and nineteen

But all are idiomatic and will be understood.

> twenty and nineteen

is not idiomatic and will not be understood.

As for what English will be like in another 8000 years, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: So, you don't know how to say 56789 year, either?

For all other information - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can ignore the fact that this number represents a year and examine the common short and long forms for reading this number aloud.

> 56,789
>   fifty-six thousand seven hundred eighty-nine
>   fifty-six seven eighty-nine

This is a bit different than the way we commonly read a four-digit number aloud.

> 1995
>   one thousand nine hundred ninety-five
>   nineteen ninety-five

There is a somewhat less common reading for that number (but a reading often used for years) which helps explain the short form.

> nineteen hundred and ninety-five

Numbers with zeros often use “oh” (or “o”) to disambiguate.

> 1906 — nineteen oh six
>   50789 — five-oh seven eighty-nine
>   56089 — fifty-six oh eighty-nine
>   56709 — fifty-six seven oh-nine

This need for disambiguation should be obvious:

> 1906 — ninteen six — 19.6?
>   50789 — fifty seven eighty-nine — 5789?
>   56089 — fifty-six eighty-nine — 5689?
>   56709 — fifty-six seven nine — 5679?

Back in 1906, *nineteen aught-six* was a more likely reading than *nineteen oh-six*.  Given the right context, *aught-six* and *oh-six* can easily stand on their own.  We might assume that, given the right context, 56789 could simply be read as *eighty-nine* or *seven eight-nine*.

Comment: But what if we don't have zeros?

56789

How would you write it then?

Comment: I answered that in the first block quote.  In a context where 2019 is twenty nineteen, 56789 can be fifty-six seven eighty-nine.

Comment: I think Zager and Evans had it right - when speaking of years in the future, we often say "the year" followed by a number, especially for the far future.. In the year 6565 ("sixty-five sixty-five")...In the year 7510 (seventy-five ten") ... In the year 8510 (eighty-five ten"). These are four-figure years, split into pairs. For the original question, I would say "the  year fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine" or "the year five six seven eight nine".